# did Polymer 1.0 break requirejs

Tags: requirejs, amd, polymer-1.0

Calling requirejs' `require` function after Polymer 1.0 has been loaded results in a [mismatch](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch) error.

This used to work fine with Polymer 0.5

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know what exactly you tried to give an informed answer. When I encountered a similar issue, The steps I took to resolve the issue was the following.

1. I removed the requirejs related script which was in the same page
   that was loading the Polymer 1.0 elements.
2. I then created a new module using a definition function, containing
   the script I had removed in step one.
3. I then loaded this new module in the page containing the Polymer 1.0
   elements using a requirejs script tag referring to the new module I
   just created, with data-main attribute. An example of script tag I used is shown below

   ```
   <script data-main="./defineTests"  src="../bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
   ```